# Efficient method to get all k combinations of a python list

Tags: python

I used the `itertools.combinations(iterable,k)` method which is pretty time consuming for large test cases. Is there any method that can make it faster.

For example, I have a list of numbers : `[1,2,3]`

All possible '2' combinations of the list : `[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *which is pretty time consuming for large test cases* Are you materialising all combinations into a list? What problem are you trying to solve where you need such a large number of combinations?

Comment: Note that `itertools.combinations()` is entirely coded in C. Without more constraints on your problem, there won't *be* a faster method, but we can perhaps avoid using `itertools.combinations()` altogether if we knew what you were trying to do here.

Comment: I was trying to find gcd's of all the combinations of the list and to solve a problem. Is there any faster way than actually finding all the combinations by this method?

Comment: So we have a [XY problem here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); perhaps ask a question about your underlying problem instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`itertoools.combinations(i, k)` is quite efficient. I suppose the reason you are finding it time consuming is because you are converting the generator to a list right away something along the lines of: `list(itertools.combinations(i, k))`. However, you can just use the values one-by-one as needed in a for loop something as follows:

```
for item in itertools.combinations(i, k):
    #do stuff with each combination
```

Comment: Yeah! I was converting it into a list and then using it later on. Will try the problem this way. Thanks!